# passing libraries through functions in typescript

Tags: typescript, function, dependency-injection, parameters, libraries

I'm building an app and, probably, I'm using the dependency-injection pattern, and passing mongoose and config libraries as parameters, the config library gives me an error. Exactly, If i hover on **config.get('dbUri')**, it says: 'Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.ts(2347)'

app.ts

```
(async () => await connectDb(mongoose, config))();
```

connect.ts

```
async function connectDb(mongoose: any, config: any):Promise<void>{
    try {
        const dbUri = config.get<string>('dbUri');
        
        await mongoose.connect(dbUri, () => {
            console.log('connected to the db');
        });
    } catch (error) {
        process.exit(1)
    }
}

export default connectDb;
```

Comment: What is `config`? where is that defined and what is its type?

Comment: config is defined in app.ts, it is a library like .dotenv

Answer (score 0):

You typed `config` as `any`, and then you try to treat it like it has a generic parameter. But it can't have a generic parameter because `any` means that typescript has no idea what this is, and it lets do anything with it.

The quick fix is removing the `<string>`:

```
const dbUri = config.get('dbUri');
```

---

However, a strongly typed solution is better here.

The type of mongoose is probably going to be the type from the `import mongoose from 'mongoose'`. It looks you'd need to get the `typeof mongoose` for that since I don't think that package exports a type for this purpose.

And then you need to type `config` as whatever `config` is. I'm going to assume your `config` is something like:

```
class ConfigService {
  get<T>(prop: string): T {
    return someConfigObject[prop]
  }
}
```

And somewhere in your dependency injection, you create an instance of that class.

After all that then you can type `connectDb` as follows:

```
import type mongooseGlobal from 'mongoose'

async function connectDb(
  mongoose: typeof mongooseGlobal,
  config: ConfigService
): Promise<void>{
  //...
}
```

The point is that you have to know the type of the object you want to pass as a parameter to a function. If a type exists, great, use it. If not, then you can use `typeof` to get the type from a value.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=57&pln=22&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBCCA7A5hCBnApgcQDYQBGAhnnAGZQQhwDkiq62tAsAFDvsDGyG8G1LAGFk5YCgDyhAFZYuMAFxwASnOgATADx8owVABo4xJAE8AfHAC8cAN4BfbnmIYMcEUjEoAyligA3YC4sW3Y4OBQsGE0AFTMACjAqMCUdPRQASiVokLYwsKhIgFcoJDgBEGFRcSlZeQBtRIgwAF1QuAc2DucTJC4KQt6YYGQ4HiQkORgAEUI4hjRMLCUYEzAsCHIEZAXsfCJSQzHPJXdPH39ArEyABSoQYGxNPwhgdTMbNrCYKBMcvP-Rrx4OpCABVXRWQEecQAOgiUVSqHitBB4OAtHSAG5PgCcf9iAB3YjAeDzJhYGFjCbyOKo3SGOLpKwWD65AHssYCPAUggoOK0KmTLDqOAwCCigAWwRBGOxbPZdixOLso2IMC4ErgcV8VCgTNZ7LCjSCLhhWAAHiS4gBGdLK9gdbhAqGeSETAluKreXwBIKMuVxbq9LVMywWQnE+CC+QzObbcl7Eh4Q5e9Lpf3sIA)

Comment: to be honest I didn't what I should insert as type. mongoose: ? ? How can i get the typeof of mongoose or, in general, of a library ?